# Memcached stops working after a while

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, memcached

I've got the following setup:

- Tomcat8
- Spring 4.2.8
- Memcached on AWS, version 1.4.34

On my tomcat8 lib folder I have:
memcached-session-manager-2.1.1.jar
memcached-session-manager-tc8-2.1.1.jar
AmazonElastiCacheClusterClient-no-version.jar

Everything works fine at the beginning, the sessions are being used from all the nodes, etc I see all the session changes, but after some period let's say 1 day or a bit more it stops working. When I say it stops working, I don't mean that the session from before it's not working, every new session will not work there. Either not stored, or not read, I have no clue because I don't see any log going on either on the application nor the catalina.out log. If I restarting the tomcat8 server, everything starts working again so I'm guessing that this might be an issue with some connector or library that gets stuck at some point.

This AmazonElastiCacheClusterClient-no-version.jar seems to be a bit old, so I'm giving it a try with version 1.1.1 from maven, but as you see it's  a bit complicated to reach any conclusion since this happens over time or at some specific conditions.

Anyone having or had a similar issue?

My Manager configuration looks like the following:

```
<Context path="/" debug="1" useHttpOnly="true">

<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
    memcachedNodes="AWS_ENDPOINT:11211"
    sticky="false"
    sessionBackupAsync="true"
    lockingMode="none"
    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
    transcoderFactoryClass="de.javakaffee.web.msm.JavaSerializationTranscoderFactory"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in exceeding the maximum item size. We used version `1.2.6` and this version didn't want to work with objects greater than 1024 KB. After moving to version `1.4.5`, the problem has gone. The newer version introduces `-I` command-line parameter, which allows adjusting maximum item size up to 128 MB.